# Confusion with application of butterfly lemma in Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

In Lemma 3.3 of Serge Lang's *Algebra*, the so-called Butterfly Lemma is proved:[image]

And then Lang proceeds to prove Schreier's Refinement Theorem (highlight mine):
[image]

In the proof of Schreier's theorem, Lang seems to be using the following:
$$u(U\cap V)/u(U\cap v) \cong v(U\cap V)/v(u\cap V)$$
But that's not what Butterfly Lemma above says… In general $v(U\cap V)\neq (U\cap V)v$, right? (Unless the group is abelian). Hence, my question:

> What justifies Lang's application of Butterfly Lemma (in the way he stated)?

Comment: @DerekHolt: Ahh of course. Thank you very much :) Totally forgot about normality condition. (Feel free to convert your comment into answer, and I shall accept it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $v$ is a normal subgroup of $V$, then $vg=gv$ for all $g \in V$, so $v(U∩V)=(U∩V)v$.